# How to do horizontal overflow scrolling or wrapping in AdaptiveCards ActionSet

Tags: adaptive-cards

I was able to modify the hostingConfig for the web renderer of Adaptive Cards to display a list of actions horizontally instead of vertically. The problem is that at a certain quantity the buttons go beyond the lateral border of the card and user can't see more than 3 or 4 actions.

Is there a way to wrap the actions so that once a button doesn't fit the width then it continues on the next line? or that the user can scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in Adaptive Cards v1.5:

https://adaptivecards.io/blog/2021/Announcing-1.5/

As youre apparently rendering cards yourself, you just have to update the library.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually using ReactWebChat to render the web chat, so not really rendering them myself. But I'm indicating version 1.2 in my cards.
I'll change that and use the new feature.